# Python: If column contains string, then extract another column's value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `DFa` and `DFb`.
`DFa` contains 4 columns: `Date`, `macro_A`, `macro_B`, `macro_C`.
Whereas, `DFb` contains 3 columns: `Name`, `Region`, `Transformation`.

What I am trying to achieve is that I wish to check if the column names of `DFa` are contained within `DFb.Name`; if yes, then I will extract the equivalent `Transformation` method from `DFb`. 
Depending on what the transformation method is, I will appropriately transform the `DFa` column.

```
DFa = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013],
'macro_A' : [0.23, 0.20, 0.13, 0.19], 
'macro_B' : [0.23, 0.20, 0.13, 0.19], 
'macro_C' : [0.23, 0.20, 0.13, 0.19]}, index = [1, 2, 3, 4])

DFb = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['macro_C', 'macro_B', 'macro_D', 'macro_A', 'macro_E'],
'Region' : ['UK', 'UK', 'US', 'UK', 'EUR'], 
'Transformation' : ['non', 'STD', 'STD', 'STD', 'non']}, 
 index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

For example, I check that `macro_A` column from `DFa` exists within `DFb.Name`. Then, I check that from `DFb.Transformation` the value is `STD`, which means I need to transform (standardize) the `DFa.macro_A`.

On the other hand, I check `macro_C` from `DFa` exists within `DFb.Name`, but `DFb.Transformation` for `macro_C` is `non`. Therefore, I leave `DFa.macro_C` as it stands.

I have build this code

```
for j, k in enumerate(DFa.columns):
    for i, x in enumerate(DFb['Name']):
        if x == k:
            if DFb.ix[i, 'Transformation'] == 'STD':
                DFa.iloc[:, j] = preprocessing.scale(DFa.iloc[: j])
```

How can I make my code more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following corrected code works:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
for j, k in enumerate(DFa.columns):
    for i, x in enumerate(DFb.Name):
        if x == k and DFb.iloc[i,:]['Transformation'] == 'STD':
            DFa.iloc[:,j] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(DFa.iloc[:,j])

print(DFa)
```

Output:

```
...some DEPRECATION_MSG warnings...
   Date  macro_A  macro_B  macro_C
1  2010      1.0      1.0     0.23
2  2011      0.7      0.7     0.20
3  2012      0.0      0.0     0.13
4  2013      0.6      0.6     0.19
```

macro_A and macro_B have been scaled but not macro_C.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can avoid the `enumerate` and `iloc` by using the column names. I will also suggest using a `string->lambda` map to store the operations and use the `apply` function. It will help when you have multiple operation strings

```
operations = {'STD': lambda x : min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x),
              'non': lambda x : x} # Operations map 

for colName in DFa.columns.values:
    transformStr = DFb.Transformation[DFb.Name == colName] #Get the transform string by matching column name with Name column

    if transformStr.shape[0] > 1 or transformStr.shape[0] == 0: # Make sure that only one operation is selected
        raise(Exception('Invalid transform string %s',transformStr))

    DFa[colName] = DFa[colName].apply(operations[transformStr.iloc[0]])
```